# Calculating tree growth using for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate diameter growth for a set of trees over a number of years in a dataframe in which each row is a given tree during a given year.  Typically, this sort of data has each individual stem as a single row with that stem's diameter for each year given in a separate column, but for various reasons, this dataframe needs to remain such that each row is an individual stem in an individual year. A simplistic model version of the data would be as follows

```
df<-data.frame("Stem"=c(1:5,1:5,1,2,3,5,1,2,3,5,6),
           "Year"=c(rep(1997,5), rep(1998,5), rep(1999,4), rep(2000,5)),
           "Diameter"=c(1:5,seq(1.5,5.5,1),2,3,4,6,3,5,7,9,15))
df
   Stem Year  DAP
1     1 1997  1.0
2     2 1997  2.0
3     3 1997  3.0
4     4 1997  4.0
5     5 1997  5.0
6     1 1998  1.5
7     2 1998  2.5
8     3 1998  3.5
9     4 1998  4.5
10    5 1998  5.5
11    1 1999  2.0
12    2 1999  3.0
13    3 1999  4.0
14    5 1999  6.0
15    1 2000  3.0
16    2 2000  5.0
17    3 2000  7.0
18    5 2000  9.0
19    6 2000 15.0
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to make a new column that takes the diameter for a given stem in a given year and subtracts the diameter for that same stem in the previous year. I assume that this will require some set of nested for loops.  Something like

```
for (i in 1:length(unique(df$Stem_ID){
  for (t in 2:length(unique(df$Year){
.....
  }
}
```

What I'm struggling with is how to write the function that calculates:
Diameter[t]-Diameter[t-1] for each stem.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Stem), function(x) transform(x, diff = c(0,diff(x$Diameter)))))
     Stem Year Diameter diff
1.1     1 1997      1.0  0.0
1.6     1 1998      1.5  0.5
1.11    1 1999      2.0  0.5
1.15    1 2000      3.0  1.0
2.2     2 1997      2.0  0.0
2.7     2 1998      2.5  0.5
2.12    2 1999      3.0  0.5
2.16    2 2000      5.0  2.0
3.3     3 1997      3.0  0.0
3.8     3 1998      3.5  0.5
3.13    3 1999      4.0  0.5
3.17    3 2000      7.0  3.0
4.4     4 1997      4.0  0.0
4.9     4 1998      4.5  0.5
5.5     5 1997      5.0  0.0
5.10    5 1998      5.5  0.5
5.14    5 1999      6.0  0.5
5.18    5 2000      9.0  3.0
6       6 2000     15.0  0.0
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed it to do.  This is much more elegant way to do this than I had in mind. Thanks so, so much!

Comment: make sure to accept his answer if it is acceptable to you!

Answer (score 0):

Rnso's answer works. You could also do the slightly shorter:

```
>df[order(df$Stem),]
>df$diff <- unlist(tapply(df$Diameter,df$Stem, function(x) c(NA,diff(x))))

   Stem Year Diameter diff
1     1 1997      1.0   NA
6     1 1998      1.5  0.5
11    1 1999      2.0  0.5
15    1 2000      3.0  1.0
2     2 1997      2.0   NA
7     2 1998      2.5  0.5
12    2 1999      3.0  0.5
16    2 2000      5.0  2.0
3     3 1997      3.0   NA
8     3 1998      3.5  0.5
13    3 1999      4.0  0.5
17    3 2000      7.0  3.0
4     4 1997      4.0   NA
9     4 1998      4.5  0.5
5     5 1997      5.0   NA
10    5 1998      5.5  0.5
14    5 1999      6.0  0.5
18    5 2000      9.0  3.0
19    6 2000     15.0   NA
```

Or if you're willing to use the data.table package you can be very succinct:

```
>require(data.table)
>DT <- data.table(df)
>setkey(DT,Stem)
>DT <- DT[,diff:= c(NA, diff(Diameter)), by = Stem]
>df <- as.data.frame(DT)

   Stem Year Diameter diff
1     1 1997      1.0   NA
2     1 1998      1.5  0.5
3     1 1999      2.0  0.5
4     1 2000      3.0  1.0
5     2 1997      2.0   NA
6     2 1998      2.5  0.5
7     2 1999      3.0  0.5
8     2 2000      5.0  2.0
9     3 1997      3.0   NA
10    3 1998      3.5  0.5
11    3 1999      4.0  0.5
12    3 2000      7.0  3.0
13    4 1997      4.0   NA
14    4 1998      4.5  0.5
15    5 1997      5.0   NA
16    5 1998      5.5  0.5
17    5 1999      6.0  0.5
18    5 2000      9.0  3.0
19    6 2000     15.0   NA
```

If you have a large dataset, data.table has the advantage of being extremely fast.